# Android BT Handover AND Start App

Tags: android, bluetooth, nfc

I'm trying to do several things at once with a single NDEF message on a tag, and I'm starting to wonder if Android actually supports what I want to do.

When I touch the phone to the tag, I want to

1. Start my application
2. Configure my application with the MAC address of a bluetooth device stored in the tag.
3. Pair the bluetooth device with minimal user interaction
4. Open a BluetoothSocket from my application to the bluetooth device.

To this end, I've created an NDEF message (I've heard android only supports 1 message), with several NDEF records.

The first is a URI record for my company's website, and I've registered an intent filter in my app to be able to catch this record.
The second is a Handover Select record containing the bluetooth mac address of a device, and randomized C and R values.
The third is an AAR record specifying my application package.

So on to the problems:

If I put the handover select record first, Android will silently pair (GOOD!) and attempt to connect to the target device (BAD!), without ever notifying my application (BAD!)

If I put the URI record first, Android will notify my activity with all the bytes on the tag (GOOD!) but I have no way to silently pair (BAD!) or make use of the randomized numbers in the Handover Select record (BAD!).  I don't see any obvious way to re-fire the Handover Select record so another activity can handle the pairing (BAD!)

In a perfect world, it would silently pair bluetooth, and notify my app so I can connect to the remote device.  Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Hey, really interesting idea. Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm thinking you would likely have to do a second tap to read and parse the NDEF Message within your app.